# Neo4J Self Lookup

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am struggling to get a simple Neo4J file to map to itself.
I have two CSV files 
File A

```
ID,Name
0,abc
1,def
2,ghi
3,JJK
```

And File B

```
ID,Primary_ID,Secondary_ID
0,2,3
```

What I am wanting is to import **File A** into the Bloom and then link to the other elements by looking up **File B** if there is a relationship.

A Neo4J expert could probably tell me what I'm doing wrong.

This is my neo4j command:

```
neo4j@neo4j> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FileB.csv' AS row
         WITH toInteger(row["ID"]) as ID, row["Primary_ID"] as Primary, row["Secondary_ID"] as Secondary
         MATCH (c:item {itemId: Secondary})
         MATCH (p:item {itemId: Primary})
         MERGE (o)-->(p)
         RETURN count(o);
```

Comment: in your fileB.csv, what do you want to achieve? what ia the expected result?

Comment: Basically I want file A to represent a bunch of Circles on the Graph and File B to draw the lines between each circle.

Comment: Google this: "neo4j create node from csv". Then run your neo4j load script to process FileB.csv.  It should work if you change c:item to o:item.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there’s a typo in your query. You used `o` instead of `c` in the `MERGE` clause.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///FileB.csv' AS row       
WITH toInteger(row["ID"]) as ID, row["Primary_ID"] as Primary, row["Secondary_ID"] as Secondary
MATCH (c:item {itemId: Secondary})
MATCH (p:item {itemId: Primary})
MERGE (c)-->(p)
RETURN count(c);
```